# Using getSelected in MooTools

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, mootools, html-select

I'm new to JS and Mootools and I've been having a really funny error using getSelected() with Mootools 1.3.2. [I've looked at other posts that have similar code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340459/mootools-how-to-use-getselected), but I haven't been successful. I'm using getSelected to try and get the value of an option and for some reason, my browser simply isn't calling it.

## Here's the HTML

```
<select id="id_method" name="method">
    <option selected="selected" value="">---------</option>
    <option value="Au">Auction (Best Price Wins)</option>
    <option value="Fi">Fixed Price</option>
    <option value="Fr">Free Item/Donation</option>
    <option value="Mu">Multiple Items and Prices</option>
    <option value="No">No Price Displayed</option>
    <option value="Tr">Trade</option>
</select>
```

## Here's the JS

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    ...

    $('id_method').addEvent('change', function() {
        alert(this.getSelected().selection[0].value);
    });
});
```

Here's my attempt at putting in in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jNYud/

I know this is probably a really silly question, but I'd appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of calling `getSelected()` returns an array, pure and simple. So you just need to look at the first element of that array. So replace your alert with this one:

```
alert(this.getSelected()[0].value);
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but no dice. I only get one alert when I run this: alert("work!"); alert($('id_method').getSelected()[0].text); alert("please?"); I tried using another version of MooTools, but no luck there, either.

Comment: @Rodrigo: What? All I did is change your fiddle to show the line I described. Worked just fine: the alert showed the item I selected. No muss, no fuss. And your new code works just fine too. So I'm guessing your real code is not like the fiddle. Or the browser you're using is different from mine: FF5.

Comment: @Rodrigo. Scrap that latter thought. Your fiddle plus my change works in the latest versions of all the major browsers.

Comment: You're right! It worked on jfiddle, too. Here was my problem: I was using Django and I did funky things on the template that made two things have an id of "id_method". (Wow, I can't begin to tell you much time that cost me :S). Thanks a lot for your patience!